# How to design an SQL database where some attributes in the table are only relevant to some rows?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have a table called Type_of_installations; it contains several types each with common fields like `cost`, `guarantee_end`, `manufacturer`...

However there are features that are related to only some types like

```
voltage, capacity, hours_per_week, lifting_power, weight, ...
```

These may exist with only some features.  One way I remember is to add a ***bit field*** after each irregular feature, but I think there are more efficient techniques to handle this.  I think it will be tiresome to check every irregular feature bit every time; this is programming time consuming rather than more processing time.

What is the best way to design a set of tables where some attributes are only relevant to some rows in the main table?

Comment: So, what is your question?

Answer (score 3):

Bit fields would work. Another way that would be more involved might be to do it EAV-style:

"installations" table fields: id,guarantee_end,manufacurer
"options" table fields: install_id,option_name,option_value

So if you have an "installations" table with your required fields where:

```
 id guarentee_end manufacurer
 1  20140101      IBM
 2  20140701      Lenovo
```

Your "options" table could have:

```
 install_id option_name option_value
 1          cost        1000.00
 1          color       green
 2          foo         bar
```

You store no more than is needed per record, without having to strictly define what those possible options are. You just add them as needed, and join on the install_id field to query them.

Comment: EAV is not a good way to go.

Comment: Might not be, but he asked for alternatives and it came to mind. Could you elaborate a bit more on why it isn't a good way to do it, and maybe give a better way to do it? I'd be curious to see it, too.

Comment: It's way better than bit fields. In general if EAV a bad way to go, shouldn't really be using a SQL db in the first place.

Comment: It's very hard to maintain integrity in an EAV design; it is very hard to write queries in an EAV design.  So, insert, update and select operations are hard.

Comment: i think it is not good way too

Comment: See http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/20763/2397 for a list of reasons against EAV.

Comment: I don't disagree with anyone one of those reasons in the article, however EAV is chosen as an effective compromise often enough for it to mentioned as an option. I've seen far worse options chosen on occasion.

Answer (score 2):

If you can define subsets of these optional columns that always appear together you can create sub-tables, each containing a subset and being linked to the main table using foreign keys.

Something like:

```
MainTable(id int, guarantee_end int, manufacturer int)
Electric(id int, voltage float, watts float, mainTableID int foreign key)
```

**EDIT:** Otherwise just have the fields be NULL when they aren't used, there's no need for a bit field (in most cases). You can combine having NULL fields with the above to get some reasonably efficient and decent structured combination.

Answer (score 2):

NoSQL might be a better route for this sort of data.

If you aren't interested in individual properties e.g. select * from Things Where lifting_power > 400, then xml or serialisation would be a goer.

Aside from  the oft used but foolish put all possible columns in the table, your best bet is a classic property bag

Thingy (ThingyID, ThingyName, etc)
Property(PropertyID, PropertyName, PropertyType, etc), seen default, min and max all sorts of things here

PropertiesOfThingys(ThingyID, PropertyID, PropertyValue) PropertyValue would be a string, and you'd use PropertyType for translation

sort of thing